# Query whether an element has more than 1 ID, if so, join them and place them back as 1 id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use either jQuery or JS to find out if an element has more than one id, then if it does, join them together with a '-', then reinsert it back into that id as one. Please see the code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="Join This" href=""></a>

<!-- result -->
<a id="join-this" href=""></a>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could grab all the elements on the page then loop through them, making sure the id has a `-` in place of spaces.

```
for(var i = 0, l = els.length; i < l; i++) {
    if(els[i].id !== '') {
        els[i].id = els[i].id.split(' ').join('-');
    }
}
```

[Example here.](https://jsfiddle.net/8m9afxsr/2/)

*Updated so it doesn't append a blank id on elements without an id*

Comment: @lucasjohnson updated it to keep your html looking a bit tidier, before it was applying an id to everything, even if it didn't have one already. e.g. `<html id> <body id>` etc.